# integer pointer is not initialized

Tags: c, pointers

I just installed visual studio 2013 and gonna try a simple code. So I write this one:

```
int main(void) {

    int length = 0;
    int *array ;
    printf("Enter the number of input: ");
    scanf_s("%d", &length);
    printf("%d", length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++){
        scanf_s("%d", array + i);
    }

    printf("shoting ........ ");

    getc;
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile this code, it says local variable "array" is not initialized .
Am I missing something ?

Comment: Cause... its not? Declaration != Initialization.

Comment: why do you have // int array[100]; commented out? your program may have gotten further.

Comment: C or C++? Pick one. They are different languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `int *array ;` declares a pointer. But you don't know where it points to. You can allocate some space using memory allocation functions like `malloc()` etc. or make it point to some other pre-allocated space. As you are asking user for the input length (i.e. don't know your memory requirement at compile time), dynamic memory allocation like `malloc()` would be the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

**Note**: This answer is applicable if you are compiling in C,not C++

```
int *array;
```

Declares a pointer of type `int*`. Since it is not initialized, it points to some random location. This is what the compiler is trying to tell you. Just allocate memory dynamically using `malloc`. Add

```
array=malloc(length*sizeof(int));
```

Just after the first `scanf_s`  to allocate enough memory. Note that you need to include `stdlib.h` to use `malloc`.
Also change

```
getc;
```

To

```
getchar();
```

It is also a good idea to check the return values of `malloc`,`scanf_s` etc to see if they are successful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to Initialize the array
such as

```
int *array = maloc(sizeof(int) * 100);
```

or

```
int *array = new int[];
```

Comment: Your second example is invalid.   An array size needs to be specified.  And malloc() has two l's.

Comment: This does not "initialize the array", it allocates some memory and initializes the pointer to point to that memory. (Assuming you fixed the problems Rob mentioned)